# The use of the colon before enumerations

Tags: lists, colons

I would like to check the correctness of two constructions containing enumerations. The first one is as follows.

> Let us note the following two aspects: First, here comes the first aspect. Second, here comes the second aspect.

Is it acceptable to begin with a capital letter after a colon? Also, is it acceptable to keep one item together with the corresponding introduction whereas the other one comes as a separate sentence?

The second construction is as follows.

> Let us note the following two aspects:
>
> First, here comes a separate paragraph with a long explanation of the first aspect.
>
> Second, here comes a separate paragraph with a long explanation of the second aspect.

Is it acceptable to end a sentence with a colon followed by two paragraphs?

The correctness of the structure of my question is also a question.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm fairly certain that by "column sign" you mean "colon"; if not, please feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: Google this phrase using the quotes: "following two areas". There seems to be almost no standardization about how people structure this. Example: (i) some text (ii) some text. Example: ... following two areas. Control systems. Power Systems. And then there's a complete web page divided down the middle: http://psychology.sas.upenn.edu/graduate/resareas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In §6.61, "Lowercase or capital letter after a colon," the Chicago Manual of Style says:

> When a colon is used within a sentence, the first word following the
>   colon is lowercased unless it is a proper name. When a colon
>   introduces two or more sentences, when it introduces a speech in
>   dialogue or an extract, or when it introduces a direct question, the
>   first word following it is capitalized.

Your first construction is certainly correct per this guideline; and your second construction is simply an elaboration of the first, and one I've seen commonly used. As a general guideline to the use of the colon, CMoS says:

> A colon introduces an element or a series of elements illustrating or
>   amplifying what has preceded the colon; use a colon sparingly,
>   however, and only to emphasize that the second clause illustrates or
>   amplifies the first. (The colon should generally convey the sense of
>   “as follows.”) The colon may sometimes be used instead of a period to
>   introduce a series of related sentences.

Comment: Heh, I was just embarking on penning an answer that quoted the exact same paragraph. I will instead just add that capitalisation after colons, and colon use in general, ***is subject to the style guide that you adhere to***. So the answer to this question depends on what you are writing (for).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Just out of curiosity, have you used a style guide that differs significantly from CMoS on this topic? (I know that some users on this site have ideological issues with CMoS...)

Comment: I don’t think so, no—but I wouldn’t be surprised if there were a style guide or two out there who advocated always capitalising after a colon, or never using a colon to ‘control’ more than one following sentence. Always best to check the style guide in matters such as this.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: This link: http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_04.htm indicates that you are correct re capitalisation preferences. One would assume that the list a colon may be used to introduce may be a list of connected sentences.